# Is it possible to subscribe to changes through an NgTemplateOutlet?

Tags: angular, angular6, eventemitter, ng-template, ng-container

I have an Angular component (ParentComponent) that accepts and displays a custom NgTemplate. I want ParentComponent to receive events from a component in the NgTemplate through an EventEmitter. Something like this:

ParentComponent.html

```
<!-- I want onCustomEvent to be called -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="childTemplate" (customEvent)='onCustomEvent($event)'>
</ng-container>
```

OtherComponent.html

```
<ng-template #child>
  <button (click)='customEvent.emit("Hello World")'>Emit</button>
</ng-template>
<parent-component [childTemplate]='child'></parent-component>
```

This is about as simple an example I could think of, so hopefully it is enough to get the point across.  Is something like this possible?  If not, what strategies can be used to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: You can use a service provided by the parent component.